# Gps mistaken my location and get me to trouble

Tags: gps-tracking

I really need ur help I hope u will do CZ I'm so in trouble with my husband becz of Gps mistakenly located my position I'm. A specialist. Pediatrician working in hospital and that day I.have oncall duty and I was working in the hospital all that time my husband can not belive I'm oncall he was tracking my position I think by my Gmail. Because he knew my email password later Gps photo showed to him that I was not at hospital and I was go out to 3 different place and he do not want to believe. Me he insulting me although all what Gps point is not true and I ask him to asks the nurses and security that night when I was oncall where I am but he do not want to believe he is trusting that Gps than me  I attached here the Gps he view showing where I have been although all the time I was working in the hospital ?is there anyway I can prove Gps being wrong or  Can I contact Google Maps and can they give an official printout of that certain day and every location I was? I really need to prove my honesty to him and hope there is a way.

Comment: Sorry to hear this. I sympathise. This relationship is being jeopardized by reliance on a technology that has a built-in margin of error. GPS is not exact. He has to come to realize this.

Comment: So what can I do now ? Does anybody out there can read the Google map Gps he saw! How I can prove he is wrong ?how I contact google map and  can they give an official printout of that certain day and every location I was on that day?? Please help

Comment: You can get your location history in Google maps, however, the GPS isn't the issue here at all is it? It is the complete lack of trust, and the utter invasion of your privacy from your husband. The GPS/WiFi/Cell location is NOT accurate and can be off by hundreds of meters radius, which is a HUGE area to cover. Really you should be talking to him and looking at your relationship. This isn't normal, it isn't right, and it's tally invasive. Lock your account and turn off 'location history' and sit down and talk to him. You said he is insulting you, this seems to be a much bigger issue tbh.

Comment: I'm thankful for all your help and sympathy technology Is sword with two sharp points offf offff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Google does track your *Android device's* location not solely on GPS. They use also WiFi Access Points and cell towers to do so. This makes not only the accuracy sometimes very inaccurate, but could also lead to false location reports.

I doubt that Google will be helpful here. This is more of a social problem then a technical one, consisting of the absolute believe in technology, which is wrong, and the distrust in persons, which is also wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this on [google location history](https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0).... and I can attest it isn't entirely accurate

[image]

(more so when the points are several kilometers apart, and I probably walked at supersonic speeds)

As @flow has said though, its more of a socio/cultural issue as a technical one - I shouldn't be judging someone elses culture but this kind of unfounded suspicion and emotional abuse isn't *right*.

Comment: It's helpful thanks you so much I hope I can convince him